# ES6 via jspm errors in Firefox, Edge, Vivaldi, but works in Chrome, Opera

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jspm, systemjs, traceur

I'm using ES6 via **jspm** + **SystemJS** + **traceur** according to jspm tutorial.

Everything works fine in Chrome and Opera, however, console posts various errors in other browsers.

Firefox: `SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier, uncaught exception: SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier`

Edge: `SCRIPT1002: Syntax error, Potentially unhandled rejection [2] Syntax error`

Vivaldi: `Unexpected token =>`

**SystemJS** [readme](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) states that it runs even IE8+.

My `jspm.config.js`:

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "traceur",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system"
    ]
  },
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },
  shim: {
    "packages": {
      "assets/js/lib/tabs": {
        "main": "tabby",
        "format": "global",
        "deps": "jquery",
        "exports": "$.tabby"
      },
      "assets/js/lib/select": {
        "main": "selectify",
        "format": "global",
        "deps": "jquery",
        "exports": "$.selectify"
      }
    }
  },

  map: {
    "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.8.25",
    "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.25",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.1",
    "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4",
    "jquery-mask-plugin": "npm:jquery-mask-plugin@1.13.4",
    "jquery-validation": "github:jzaefferer/jquery-validation@1.14.0",
    "selectify": "assets/js/lib/select",
    "tabby": "assets/js/lib/tabs",
    "traceur": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur@0.0.91",
    "traceur-runtime": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.91",
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
      "assert": "npm:assert@1.3.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.11.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "github:jzaefferer/jquery-validation@1.14.0": {
      "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4"
    },
    "npm:assert@1.3.0": {
      "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
    },
    "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.25": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:core-js@1.2.1": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:inherits@2.0.1": {
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:process@0.11.2": {
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:util@0.10.3": {
      "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    }
  }
});
```

And `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "project_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "project_description",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "project_author",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "glob": "^5.0.15",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-concat-css": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-jspm": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.2.0",
    "jspm": "^0.16.11"
  },
  "jspm": {
    "configFile": "jspm.config.js",
    "dependencies": {
      "jquery": "github:components/jquery@^2.1.4",
      "jquery-mask-plugin": "npm:jquery-mask-plugin@^1.13.4",
      "jquery-validation": "github:jzaefferer/jquery-validation@^1.14.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4",
      "traceur": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur@0.0.91",
      "traceur-runtime": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.91"
    }
  }
}
```

Desperate to solve this situation, as I understand, that there could be many reasons for it. Maybe someone run across similar issue with that setup.

Comment: It looks like your classes are not being transpiled into ES5 by traceur.

Comment: Why does your config mention both `babel` _and_ `traceur`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth: this is mainly for test purposes, as I was trying to switch the transpiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

This was due to one of the plugins, which was provided in `jspm.config.js` shim. The plugin was using an `Immediately-Invoked Arrow Function` notation and word `class` without any export directive, and thus, shim plugin wasn't transpiled into **ES5**.

So instead of using **ES6** classes in third-party libraries (shim plugins) it should be build with simple prototypal inheritance.

Cost me several hours to find out.